# top links css not showing in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php, theme, css, toplinks

I am using magento 1.8.0. I have added new toplink in header. I have added following code in customer.xml file of my theme :

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>Track</label>
        <url>track-order-status</url>
        <title>Track Your Order</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <liParams/>
        <aParams>class="top-link-tracking"</aParams>
        <beforeText></beforeText>
        <afterText></afterText>
      </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

I have added the css for the "top-link-tracking" class in style.css properly and cleared all caches. Link is visible at the toplinks portion but with NO CSS. Any solution?

Comment: It's good to have the XML fragment from your `customer.xml`. This question is about CSS not working, right? I think it would be more useful to have the HTML + CSS fragments. Could you provide the HTML output of the top link? Could you provide the CSS that you are trying to set to it?

Comment: Sorry ..can you please expain what you said?